# adding continues 5 days between two given dates in SAS EG

Tags: sas

What am I trying to do is the following:

Have this table:

Table1

```
Item Date1 Date 2
1    6/1/2021  7/31/2021
2    7/4/2021  7/30/2021
3    6/20/2021 7/28/2021
....
```

My want table is the following:

```
Item   Date
1      6/1/2021
1      6/6/2021
1      6/11/2021
1      6/16/2021
...
```

Basically I am trying to create a date by incrementing 5 days from the start date until the last date.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you started:

```
data want;
set have;
format date date1 date2 date9.;
do Date=date1 to date2 by 5;
   Date = MIN(Date, Date2);
   output;
end;
*keep Item Date;
run;
```